# Configure Access-Control-Allow-Origin for clients with origin: null

Tags: same-origin-policy, cors

I develop a web app. When I run the app on Android, origin in the header of a network request is `null`. Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response header is `null` too, because the origin of the resource is something like `file://...`, which is changed to `null`. Since the last update, Chrome blocks this request with the following message:

> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not
>   equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an
>   opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'
>   to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I found two possible solutions:

a) Disable CORS

b) Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to `*`

I didn't have the chance to try these solutions yet. However,

1. **Is there an advantage in allowing any origin over disabling CORS?** There must be one, otherwise this option is nonsense...
2. **What's the best web server configuration to serve web apps with origin `null`?**

Comment: clarify: how does the client affect the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` _response_ header? You must be serving the response from some origin, right? also, how do you "disable cors"?

Comment: As I understand, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header depends on origin in the request header. Origin in request header is `null` because the web app running on Android has a `file://` URL. 
We're using IIS and I found some manual about how to enable CORS. So I assumed CORS can be disabled. But when I think about it now, it might be better to support CORS but allow all origins.
FYI: The webserver is in a private network but there are many devices to access it.
I hope I could clarify the situation, althought I don't understand CORS well.
I'll edit the question, if this info helps.

Comment: I think I'll have to solve the problem in the client. The react-native app opens the web app with something like `<WebView source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/web/index.html }} />`
I don't know how to solve this yet, but I'll try to change the client rather than the server. Why is a file URL not mapped to `origin: localhost`? I wouldn't have any problems than ;-)

Comment: In IIS configuration CORS can be disabled.